# Как правильно запустить тесты на yii2 в докере?

Tags: ubuntu, yii2, docker, тестирование, testng

Запустил в ubuntu на докере yii2-basic и пробую реализовать простой тест, создал в папке tests/acceptance простой файл командой "vendor/bin/codecept generate:cept acceptance TestGuestPages" и в появившемся файле TestGuestPages написал простой тест:

```
<?php
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Open the page');
$I->amOnPage('/');
$I->see('Welcome', 'h1');
```

Далее пробую запустить тест командой vendor/bin/codecept run, но получаю ошибку

```
zz@zz-Inspiron-5720:~/projects/school$  vendor/bin/codecept run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.4.5
Powered by PHPUnit 7.2.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Acceptance Tests (6) -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E TestGuestPagesCept: Open the page 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stop() on 
null in /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php:346
Stack trace:
#0 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Subscriber/Module.php(66): Codeception\Module\Yii2->_after(Object(Codeception\Test\Cept))
#1 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(212): Codeception\Subscriber\Module->after(Object(Codeception\Event\TestEvent), 'test.after', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#2 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'test.after', Object(Codeception\Event\TestEvent))
#3 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Listener.php(133): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('test.after', Object(Codeception\Event\TestEvent))
#4 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Listen in /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php on line 346

FATAL ERROR. TESTS NOT FINISHED.
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stop() on null in /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php:346
Stack trace:
#0 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Subscriber/Module.php(66): Codeception\Module\Yii2->_after(Object(Codeception\Test\Cept))
#1 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(212): Codeception\Subscriber\Module->after(Object(Codeception\Event\TestEvent), 'test.after', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#2 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'test.after', Object(Codeception\Event\TestEvent))
#3 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Listener.php(133): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('test.after', Object(Codeception\Event\TestEvent))
#4 /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Listen 
in /home/zz/projects/school/vendor/codeception/base/src/Codeception/Module/Yii2.php:346
```

Пробовал запустить через docker-compose exec web vendor/bin/codecept run, но результат такой же.
Не пойму, с чем связана такая ошибка, ответа в сети не нашел, подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже не установлен Codeception. Проверьте, что composer установил все зависимости.

Comment: Команда vendor/bin/codecept --version выводит версию
Codeception 2.4.5. Также и команда docker-compose exec web vendor/bin/codecept --version выводит версию

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась. Оказывается в файле `acceptance.suite.yml` были неправильные настройки.